# Error 3013: Failed to open setup executable

Tags: java, installation, netbeans-7

hi i have problem to make my application java executable, am using setup facotry 9 after i followed all the steps i get this erreur

```
 > Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\wataiik1.form
... compression ratio: 98% (884253 bytes -> 14577 bytes)
> Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\wataiik1.java
... compression ratio: 92% (386831 bytes -> 28822 bytes)
> Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\YY.png
... compression ratio: 0% (4358 bytes -> 4358 bytes)
> Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\ZA.png
... compression ratio: 0% (3528 bytes -> 3528 bytes)
> Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\ZZ.png
... compression ratio: 0% (1368 bytes -> 1368 bytes)
> Compressing: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\projet_application\src\projet_application\ZZA.png
... compression ratio: 0% (1080 bytes -> 1080 bytes)
> Compressing: D:\3ème année UCD\projets\Nouveau dossier (2)\2034\final3\BIEN4\projet_application\II.bmp
... compression ratio: 52% (2816 bytes -> 1344 bytes)
> Compressing: D:\3ème année UCD\projets\Nouveau dossier (2)\2034\final3\BIEN4\projet_application\W.bmp
... compression ratio: 67% (30056 bytes -> 9901 bytes)
Processing While Installing screens...
Creating setup configuration file...
Initializing archive file...
Creating archive header...
> Launcher manifest
> Writing version information
> Setup engine
> Setup manifest
Error 3013: Failed to open setup executable: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\_ir_sf_build_0\ir_tmp_rtm.tmp

Build failed - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s)
```